# Normal Bundle is a manifold in Pollack

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

I am reading a proof in Pollack on page 71 and in one of the steps in the proof that $N(Y) = \{ (y,v) \in Y \times N_y(Y) \}$ is a manifold, he claims that

$N(U) = N(Y) \cap (U \times \mathbb{R}^M)$ where $U = \tilde{U} \cap Y = \phi^{-1}(0)$. Here $\phi: \tilde{U} \to \mathbb{R}^{codim Y}$ is a submersion and from what I understood, he is defining $Y$ to be the preimage of $0$ of some function and $\phi^{-1}$ just happens to map $0$ to an open set in $Y$.

Now what I don't understand here is the equality $$N(U) = N(Y) \cap (U \times \mathbb{R}^M)$$

I understand the inclusion $\subset $ but not the other.

Comment: You should add some more context. I believe $Y$ is embedded in $\mathbf R^M$ to begin with. Further,  $N_y(Y)$ is the orthogonal complement of the tangent space of $Y$ at $y$, where the latter has been identified as a subspace of $\mathbf R^M$.

Comment: @caffeinemachine, you are correct sorry. Also in this definition of the normal space, are we equipping the space with an inner product? There is no mention of it, but is it there?

Comment: That's the thing, in Guillemin and Pollack, all manifold's sit inside Euclidean spaces to begin with. So the tangent spaces are naturally thought of as subspaces of $\mathbf R^n$. Then using the standard inner product of $\mathbf R^n$, we can define the normal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Both sets are $\{(u,v)|u\in U \text{ and } v\in N_u(Y) \}$.

Comment: Well that is my issue, I don't see that. I only see $\subset$. I mean $N(U) = \{ (u,v) \in U \times N_u(U) \}$.

Comment: Are we saying $N_u(Y) = N_u(U)$? Is there an obvious explanation that I am not seeing?

Comment: Yes. I think we are assuming $\tilde{U}$ is open, so $U$ is automatically open in $Y$. So $N_u(Y)=N_u(U)$.

Comment: Yes $\tilde(U)$ is open by definition and hence $U$ is open in $Y$. But why does that make the normal space the same...? Sorry if this sounds stupid

Comment: Do you know why the tangent spaces are the same?

Comment: From what I understand we are taking the tangent space at the neighbhood of the point. Taking the image, this is the $T_x(U)$ and since our chart $\psi$ maps the neighbhood inside $U \subset X$, we have the first inclusion. But relabelling $U$ by $X$ we are still mapping the neighbhood into $U \subset X$. I guess that's why. But now I am confused about the next step as it claims $\ker (d\phi_y) = T_y(Y)$